# I want to ask about error in code block in Django

Tags: django

[image: This is code for a template which i am trying to inherit]

This is code for a template which i am trying to inherit. This is not giving any error in programme but what these warning are trying to suggest

Comment: It looks like it simply does not understand Django's template mechanisms, and thus says that `{% block css %} {% endblock %}` is not valid css syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, VSCode uses linters tools to analyze code errors. Linters can show the errors and warnings you see there.

If the installed linter doesn't support the syntax/wasn't written for this syntax, it will throw an error/warning. It's common to see those, and you can force-ignore them on VSCode Settings ([More info here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)).

You can also change and set the linter by yourself on settings, or you can install an extension that does that for you.